# Draw on captured image with canvas and save to sdcard - broken display - android

Tags: android, bitmap, save, android-canvas, sd-card

I take a picture and want to draw a rectangle on it by placing the rectangle with finger gestures.

Everything is working fine and displayed correct while interacting with the screen. But when I want to save the image with the rectangles on the sdcard I get an image with correct image background, but a little bit broken rectangles. They look like somebody has snipped out some parts of them. You can perceive that they were once rectangles but the look like crap.

My Question is WHY?

I had big trouble saving everything on one canvas and this to the sdcard, because of my thread, where I cannot set the bitmap for the canvas. After using two canvases it's working like I said, but the rectangles are broken.
When I draw the rectangles without the underlying image-bitmap on the canvas, the rectangles are saved correctly.
I really don't get it. I tried everything I could imagine, but don't get the error.

I try to post a short example of my whole code:

```
public class Mark extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mark);

        p = new Panel(this);
        frLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.preview);
        frLayout.addView(p);

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_path + "/img.jpg", options);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_capturedImage);

        bitmapAll = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                try {
                    out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmapAll.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();

                    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                            file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(),
                            file.getName());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    class Panel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        private TutorialThread _thread;
        Canvas myCanvas;

        public Panel(Context context) {
            super(context);
            getHolder().addCallback(this);
            _thread = new TutorialThread(getHolder(), this);
            setFocusable(true);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            synchronized (_thread.getSurfaceHolder()) {

                switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
                    ... save the coordinates for the rectangle ...
                }

                return true;
        }


        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            myCanvas = new Canvas(bitmapAll);

            Paint paint = new Paint();

            myCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);

            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_OVER));

            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(3);

            Rect rect;

            for (...go over every saved rectangle ...) {
                rect.set(...coordinates...);
                canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
                myCanvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
            }
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            _thread.setRunning(true);
            _thread.start();
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            boolean retry = true;
            _thread.setRunning(false);
            while (retry) {
                try {
                    _thread.join();
                    retry = false;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class TutorialThread extends Thread {
        private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;
        private Panel _panel;
        private boolean _run = false;

        public TutorialThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Panel panel) {
            _surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
            _panel = panel;
        }

        public void setRunning(boolean run) {
            _run = run;
        }

        public SurfaceHolder getSurfaceHolder() {
            return _surfaceHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Canvas c;
            while (_run) {
                c = null;
                try {
                    c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                    synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {
                        _panel.onDraw(c);
                    } 
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                } finally {
                    if (c != null) {
                        _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```